# iccube set filter selection from custom widget (JS)

Tags: javascript, iccube, iccube-reporting

Using icCube 5.0, I created a custom widget using google maps, on which I draw polygons representing zones. From the JS code of this widget, I was able to update the selected items of a tree filter containing these zones as well.
So that, user could select the wanted zones either by the tree filter OR the Map. Each one updating the other.

I was using the following code to do that :

```
Chart.prototype.producedEvents = function () {
        return [vizEventType.onSelection];
    };

self.fireEvent(vizEventType.onSelection, new viz.SetSelectionEvent(SelectedZones));
```

I upgraded to version 5.1.6, this is not working. Looks as 'new viz.SetSelectionEvent' is not working anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SetSelectionEvent was moved to the proper package. Try to use:

```
new viz.event.SetSelectionEvent(SelectedZones)
```